# Why getting two different answers when trying to figure out the probability of a single event?

Tags: probability

**Question:** Two cards are drawn at random with replacement from a deck of $52$ cards. What is the probability of drawing kings of different colour?

**Approach $1$:**

Suppose, $P(A) = Probability \ of \ getting \ a \ king \ card \ of \ RED \ colour = \frac{2}{52}$ 
and $P(B) = Probability \ of \ getting \ a \ king \ card \ of \ BLACK \ colour = \frac{2}{52}$

So, when the first king card is red and the second king card is black,

$P(A \cap B) = P(A).P(B) = \frac{2}{52} . \frac{2}{52} = \frac{1}{676}$

And, when the first king card is black and the second king card is red,

$P(B \cap A) = P(B).P(A) = \frac{2}{52} . \frac{2}{52} = \frac{1}{676}$

Since, both events are mutually exclusive,

Probability  of  drawing  kings  of    different  colour $= P(A \cap B) + P(B \cap A) = \frac{1}{676}+\frac{1}{676}= \frac{1}{338} \approx 0.0030$

**Approach $2$:**

Probability  of  drawing  kings  of    different  colour $= 1 - Probability \ of \ drawing \ kings \ of \ same \ colour$

So, when the first king card is red and the second king card is also red,

$Probability \ of \ drawing \ red \ kings, P(C) = \frac{2}{52} . \frac{2}{52} = \frac{1}{676}$

And, when the first king card is black and the second king card is also black,

$Probability \ of \ drawing \ black \ kings, P(D) = \frac{2}{52} . \frac{2}{52} = \frac{1}{676}$

Probability  of  drawing only black  kings or only red kings $= P(C) + P(D) = \frac{1}{676}+\frac{1}{676}= \frac{1}{338}$

So, Probability  of  drawing  kings  of    different  colour $= 1 - \frac{1}{338} = \frac{337}{338} \approx 0.99$

Could someone please explain why I'm getting two different answers?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your second approach is clearly far too high and starts with an incorrect statement, as there are possibilities other than drawing two kings.  Instead you can say *the probability of drawing kings of different colour is the probability of drawing kings minus the probability of drawing kings of same colour*.

Comment: Your second approach completly misses that you assume to draw kings at all. So you calculate the probability of NOT drawing two kings of the same color, what's also fulfilled for e.g. two nines. 
In your first approach you guarantee to draw kings.

Comment: Is there any ways to correctly determine when to use complement approach for solving probability problems?

Comment: @Henry wow! I have never thought of it this way.

Comment: @Gono I understand. I think I need to practice more to be able to decide when to use complement approach correctly.

Comment: $1-\frac1{338}$ is the probability of "not drawing two kings of the same color". But that is not the same event as "drawing two kings of different color". You should not subtract from $1$ but from the probability of "drawing two kings".

Comment: @drhab I was assuming this, but I wasn't a 100% sure whether this was the case or not. Thank you for your comment.